# Crawling user is showing in SPContext.Current.User

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search

In our SharePoint site we are running continuous crawl. Since crawling is happening all the time in site, in my site when I'm getting user from current context, it's showing SharePoint crawl user so that my code is breaking in many places.

Could any one provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

When crawling, SharePoint Access all the pages like a normal user does. You can´t avoid that.

What you can do is to check if the current request to the site is coming from the crawler

```
SPUtility.IsSearchRequest(this.Page.Request);
```

and handle that request separately (eg Rendering and doing nothing at all if there is no Need the crawl the Output)

Comment: How do we handle it if it's search request??

Comment: if you don´t want to return anything to the crawler, do nothing and return. Or Response.End or anything else you want to have in the search index.
it´s upt to you. 
If your code is breaking if it is a search request, just don´t execute it, if it is a search request (as Long as the Output does not contain Information you do want to find in the index)

Comment: does the requests comes in queue??if i return search request..will i be able to get the expected result?or will it be lost?